# How to enable debug level log under OpenBMC using phosphor-logging

Tags: systemd-journald, openbmc

I'm bringup up an OpenBMC and modifying an application in it.
I added a debug level log but those are not printed though I changed log level using "systemctl log-level debug".

For example,

- Code:

```
        }
        jsonObject["ControllerInfo"] = controllerInfoJson;
        phosphor::logging::log<phosphor::logging::level::DEBUG>(
            "OK getting controller list");
    }
```

- CLI:

```
root@archercity:~# systemctl log-level debug
root@archercity:~# systemctl log-level
debug
root@archercity:~# journalctl | grep "controller list"
  [Nothing printed]
```

It seems like that there is something that I don't know and failed to google it too...
Could anyone enlighten me?